# Converting non printable ASCII character to binary

Tags: c

I am trying to convert a string of non-printable ASCII character to binary. Here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char str[32];
    sprintf(str,"\x01\x00\x02");

    printf("\n[%x][%x][%x]",str[0],str[1],str[2]);
    return 1;
}
```

I expect the output should be [1][0][2], but it prints [1][0][4].

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I think its something to do with "\x00". For example if I replace "\x00" in the above example with \x01, the output is file [1][1][2] ... still confused

Comment: Note: To determine, in a portable way, if an `int` is printable character, use `#include <ctype.h> isprint(x)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C strings end with a null byte, so `sprintf` only reads until `\x00`. Instead, you can use `memcpy` ([like this](http://ideone.com/VaR0BN)) or simply initialize with

```
char str[32] = "\x01\x00\x02";
```

Answer (score 6):

The `sprintf` operation ended at the first instance of `\x00` in your string literal, because NUL (U+0000) *terminates strings* in C.  (That the compiler does not complain when you write `\x00` inside a string literal is arguably a misfeature of the language.)  Thus `str[2]` accesses uninitialized memory and the program is entitled to print complete nonsense or even crash.

To do what you wanted to do, simply eliminate the `sprintf`:

```
int main(void)
{
    static const unsigned char str[32] = 
    { 0x01, 0x00, 0x02 };  // will be zero-filled to declared size

    printf("[%02x][%02x][%02x]\n", str[0], str[1], str[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

(Binary data should always be stored in arrays of *unsigned* char, not plain char; or `uint8_t` if you have it.  Because U+0000 terminates strings, I think it's better style to write embedded binary data using an array literal rather than a string literal; but it is more typing.  The `static const` is just because the data is never modified and known at compile time; the program would work without it.  Don't declare `argc` and `argv` if you're not going to use them.  Return zero, not one, from `main` to indicate successful completion.)

(Using `sprintf` the way you were using it is a bad idea for other reasons: for instance, if your binary block contained `\x25` (also known as `%` in ASCII), it would try to read additional arguments-to-be-formatted, and again print complete nonsense or crash. If you have a good reason to not just use static initialized data, the right way to copy blocks of binary data around is `memcpy`.)

Comment: you r rite .. i understand now .. thks

Comment: +1 as this solution nicely deals with non-ASCII like `'\x80'` by using unsigned.  It then prints out as "[0x80]" rather than "[ffffff80]".

Answer (score 3):

"\x00" terminates the format string which is the 2nd argument of the sprint() prematurely. Obviously that was unintentional but there is no ways sprint() can figure out that the first NUL is not the last NUL. So the format string it works on is actually shorter than what you intended to pass.